# Which bibliographystyle should I use for the reference style mentioned?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am new to Latex environment and I am in a position to prepare references for the below style as in the image:[image]

But the manual not mentioned properly about the bibliography style. But it has a .bbl file for reference purpose in a zip file.

***The sample .bbl file format as in zip file:***

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[Aghion and Durlof 2005]{aghion}
Aghion,~P \& Durlof,~S 2005, 
\newblock `Handbook of Economic Growth',
\newblock Elsevier books,
\newblock Amsterdam.

\bibitem[Albert 1975]{albert}
Albert,~Le 1975,
\newblock Nuclear Model,
\newblock Hoxen,
\newblock New York.

\bibitem[Alshahi et al 2009]{alishahi}
Alishahi,~K.~L, Marvasti,~F \& Aref~Lee~Mathew 2009,
\newblock Bounds on the sum capacity of synchronous binary CDMA channels,
\newblock Journal of Chemical Education,
\newblock Vol.~55, no.~8, pp.~3577--3593.

\end{thebibliography}
```

***Sample .bib values:***

```
@ARTICLE{1, 
author={D. C. {Rapaport}}, 
journal={Computing in Science Engineering}, 
title={Molecular dynamics simulation}, 
year={1999}, 
volume={1}, 
number={1}, 
pages={70-71}, 
}

@ARTICLE{2, 
author={A. {Bryden} and G. {Phillips} and M. {Gleicher}}, 
journal={IEEE Transactions on Visualization and Computer Graphics}, 
title={Automated Illustration of Molecular Flexibility}, 
year={2012}, 
volume={18}, 
number={1}, 
pages={132-145}, 
}

@ARTICLE{3, 
author={R. F. {Tinker} and Q. {Xie}}, 
journal={Computing in Science Engineering}, 
title={Applying Computational Science to Education: The Molecular Workbench Paradigm}, 
year={2008}, 
volume={10}, 
number={5}, 
pages={24-27}, 
}
```

I use the below Latex code as:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Random citation \cite{DUMMY:2} embeddeed in text.\cite{DUMMY:1}

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib} 

\bibliographystyle{auapalike}

\end{document}
```

I use PDFLaTeX for compile purpose in the editor. But I couldn't get output as per in the image as well as .bbl file. So guide me to get the ***PDF file*** for the mentioned output through ***.bbl file*** using ***.bib file*** in latex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share a few more details about the journal and its LaTeX template (I'm assuming you are submitting to a publisher and are using their LaTeX template because you mention a manual)? While you have used the tag `biblatex` the fact that you mention `.bbl` files makes me doubt very much that you can use `biblatex`, since most publishers can't deal with `biblatex` and their templates usually use BibTeX.

Comment: In any case you may want to change `no` in your `.bib` entries to `number` (i.e. `number = {5},` instead of `no = {5},`) since that is the standard BibTeX name for that field that most styles should be using.

Comment: @ moewe: I am new and I have basic idea only to Latex environment. I don't have more knowledge about `biblatex` vs `BibTeX`. The manual has zip file and it has .bbl file for reference purpose. In editor I use PDFLaTeX to compile. For your understanding I edit the question and add their .bbl file samples. After that please guide me to get the mentioned reference output. Thanks

Comment: An inspection of the bbl file shows that the actual formatting is **not fully consistent** with the stated formatting objectives. For instance, the formatting objective clearly states a `vol.` (with lowercase "v") prefix in front of the `volume` number for pieces published in journals. In contrast, the bbl file contains the prefix string `Vol.`. Your best option, in all likelihood, is to run the `makebst` utility (part of the `custom-bib` package) and create a bespoke bibliography style file that incorporates all formatting requirements.

Comment: @ Mico: Thank you very much for your valuable suggestion. I tried by browsing in internet as per your guidelines. But I couldn't achieve desired output due to my novice knowledge in Latex. If you don't mind can you support me to get the output with latex code as you mentioned? I have spent more time for this, but I couldn't solve this problem. Support me for my situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The edit makes it pretty clear that `biblatex` can't be involved here, so I removed the tag. pdfLaTeX is also not relevant. There are lots of `.bst` files/`\bibliographystyle`s out there, but I don't know any that would give you the exact output you want. Due to the arcane language of `.bst` files (a sort of reverse Polish notation) it is quite cumbersome and certainly at the beginning tricky to write your own bibliography style. `makebst` can be a very good tool to get started, but it might not get you there all the way. ...

Comment: ... If all else fails it is always possible to manually edit the `.bbl` file to fine-tune the output. If the bibliography isn't that large this becomes more viable.

Comment: @ moewe and @ Mico: Thank you for your valuable suggestions. I will try to do it manually. But the thing is I have huge references.. Thanks..

Comment: I continue to believe that you'll achieve your formatting objectives by running the `makebst` utility. (Aside: I did *not* suggest that you "browse the Internet" -- that's pretty much guaranteed to be hopeless!) Get started by opening a command window and typing "latex makebst". The utility runs through a structured set of questions, each with multiple-choice answers, one of which is marked as the default. The end product will be a bespoke bst file that meets your formatting needs. When you're done, copy the bst file into the directory where your tex files are located.

Comment: @Mico: Thank you very much for your suggestion.. I will try with makebst.. Thanks..