# How to generate custom bbl file from bib file in Latex?

Tags: bibtex

I need to generate following .bbl file format as like below

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[Aghion and Durlof 2005]{aghion}
Aghion,~P \& Durlof,~S 2005, 
\newblock `Handbook of Economic Growth',
\newblock Elsevier books,
\newblock Amsterdam.

\bibitem[Albert 1975]{albert}
Albert,~Le 1975,
\newblock Nuclear Model,
\newblock Hoxen,
\newblock New York.

\bibitem[Alshahi et al 2009]{alishahi}
Alishahi,~K.~L, Marvasti,~F \& Aref~Lee~Mathew 2009,
\newblock Bounds on the sum capacity of synchronous binary CDMA channels,
\newblock Journal of Chemical Education,
\newblock Vol.~55, no.~8, pp.~3577--3593.

\end{thebibliography}
```

from the sample .bib file as like below

```
@ARTICLE{1, 
author={D. C. {Rapaport}}, 
journal={Computing in Science Engineering}, 
title={Molecular dynamics simulation}, 
year={1999}, 
volume={1}, 
number={1}, 
pages={70-71}, 
}

@ARTICLE{2, 
author={A. {Bryden} and G. {Phillips} and M. {Gleicher}}, 
journal={IEEE Transactions on Visualization and Computer Graphics}, 
title={Automated Illustration of Molecular Flexibility}, 
year={2012}, 
volume={18}, 
number={1}, 
pages={132-145}, 
}

@ARTICLE{3, 
author={R. F. {Tinker} and Q. {Xie}}, 
journal={Computing in Science Engineering}, 
title={Applying Computational Science to Education: The Molecular Workbench Paradigm}, 
year={2008}, 
volume={10}, 
number={5}, 
pages={24-27}, 
}
```

I used the following code in Latex as

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\bibliography{ref} 
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\end{document}
```

But it generates .bbl file as like below

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{1}
D.~C. {Rapaport}, ``Molecular dynamics simulation,'' {\em Computing in Science
  Engineering}, vol.~1, no.~1, pp.~70--71, 1999.

\bibitem{2}
A.~{Bryden}, G.~{Phillips}, and M.~{Gleicher}, ``Automated illustration of
  molecular flexibility,'' {\em IEEE Transactions on Visualization and Computer
  Graphics}, vol.~18, no.~1, pp.~132--145, 2012.

\bibitem{3}
R.~F. {Tinker} and Q.~{Xie}, ``Applying computational science to education: The
  molecular workbench paradigm,'' {\em Computing in Science Engineering},
  vol.~10, no.~5, pp.~24--27, 2008.

\end{thebibliography}
```

This is not matched with my expected format. Guide me to get my expected format in latex. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.bbl` files like this can not be created by `biblatex`/Biber. They need to be generated by BibTeX with an appropriate `.bst` file.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511977/35864

Comment: Thank you very much..

Comment: It is impossible to generate the three bbl entries from the three bib entries, as they represent completely different publications. Aside: The name "Durlof" contains a very bad typo. it should be spelled "Durlauf".

Comment: @Mico: ok.. Thank you very much for your valuable response..